# UNKOWN_PRODUCER_ID and deleting store-changelog topic

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

kafka-streams creates lots of implicit topics depending the topology of our kafka-stream, lately while we made some incompatible changes in the avro schemas, we told our administrators to delete these topics and also store directories for the kafka-stream stores.

Now we started to see some UnkownProducerIdException in our logs. Can deleting these implicit Topics create such exception?

We always assumed, if we delete these topics and stores when we will restart the kafka-stream application, those will created and maintained automatically, is this assumption correct?

I see in apache JIRA issues KAFKA-6817, KAFKA-7190 and KIP-360 for UNKOWN_PRODUCER_ID but those doesn't seem to be directly related with out.

What should be correct action for our case (changed AVRO Schema), are we allowed to delete those implicit topics and store or we should do something else.

Also does 'auto.topic.create.enable' flag has any effect on the creation of those implicit topics?

Thx for answers.

Answer (score 0):

> Now we started to see some UnkownProducerIdException in our logs. Can deleting these implicit Topics create such exception?

Yes.

> We always assumed, if we delete these topics and stores when we will restart the kafka-stream application, those will created and maintained automatically, is this assumption correct?

Yes, Kafka Streams will recreate those topics.

> Also does 'auto.topic.create.enable' flag has any effect on the creation of those implicit topics?

No. Kafka Streams does not rely on auto topic creation (in fact, it is in general recommend to disable auto topic creation) but issues an explicit create topic request via `AdminClient`.

Comment: Is there anything special we can/should do to prevent UnkownProducerIdException after deleting these topics?

Comment: No. It's internal to Kafka. There is also a know bug with regard to `UnkownProducerIdException` that you might hit: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-360%3A+Improve+handling+of+unknown+producer